# ASP.NET how to encode into Chinese?

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding, globalization, chinese-locale

I am currently helping a Chinese colleague migrating an ASP.NET app to a different server and we have now run into a character encoding problem. What is supposed to look like Chinese looks like gibberish.

The strings presented by the ASP.NET web pages have been coded in Chinese ...

Example:

```
<input id="BQuery" value="  查询  " runat="server" class="BottonLoginRed" name="Button1" type="button" />
```

The Web.config file is configured like so ...

```
<globalization requestEncoding="gb2312" responseEncoding="gb2312" />
```

Since the source code contains Chinese encoded characters I figured I needed to set the correct culture for the response thread by adding a "culture" setting for "Simplified Chinese" in the Web.config file, like so ...

```
<globalization culture="zh-Hans" requestEncoding="gb2312" responseEncoding="gb2312" />
```

... but that produces this error message:
"Culture 'zh-Hans' is a neutral culture. It cannot be used in formatting and parsing and therefore cannot be set as the thread's current culture."

I have tried all variants for Chinese encoding, such as "zh-Hant", "zh-CHS" or just "zh" but they all yield the same problem. Apparently, there is no way to run Chinese as the response thread culture.

What would be the correct approach to resolve this issue?

[EDIT]
Apparently, my Chinese colleague has "solved" this problem before by simply setting Chinese as the language for the server itself. This is no longer an option (we'll have other apps, for different cultures running on the same server) but it might provide a hint.

[EDIT 2]
When I removed the encoding hints from the Web.config file it works. So, why is it we need to use these hints at all these days? Is it just me or is character encoding something that's being perceived as a very messy subject by everyone? :-)

Comment: have you tried zh-CN ? i found it [here](http://techmantium.com/culture-codes/)

Comment: Tried it and while I don't get an error it doesn't resolve the encoding problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you continuously update your question, you will push it up in the activity ordered list. then you might get more viewers and maybe an answer ;)

Comment: When I thought about this I realized that, since the C# and ASP.NET files are all in Unicode to start with, why is there even a need to encode/decode it? So I tried removing the globalization hints from the Web.config file and, voilá, it works.

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it, will ya? maybe it helps other people. noone looks in the question Post for an answer

Comment: I'll do that but I just wanna give everyone some more time to extend their thoughts since I honestly can't say I really understand the underlying mechanism here.

Comment: I think that's because requestEncoding and responseEncoding are default utf-8 encoded. If you force `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />` it will work as well